# Ubuntu, Siemens router and resolving the localhost

Tags: ubuntu, router, localhost, resolv.conf

after installing anew Ubuntu 11.04 can't resolve to localhost. I'm trying:

```
root@valk-pc:~# nslookup localhost
Server:     10.0.0.138
Address:    10.0.0.138#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find localhost: No answer
```

My /etc/resolv.conf has this:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain siemens
search siemens
nameserver 10.0.0.138
```

And /etc/hosts contains a valid localhost entries. What can be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I found this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=766628), and as it's there, in mine case as well, when I tried

```
sudo ping localhost
```

then I got a correct answer.

So I tried changing /etc/hosts to

```
chmod 777
```

and it worked. Finally chmod'ed it to 644 and the problem is now resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to resolve localhost with `nslookup` is probably normal - it's specifically for querying nameservers, and unless the nameserver you're querying has a record for localhost, you won't get a response.

On Linux (and any other UNIX-alike system), you'll find an entry for localhost in `/etc/hosts`:-

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

Not sure why you're trying to resolve localhost, but if you're having problems, check in `/etc/hosts` first.

**Edit:** looking at your other post, I'm not sure why you're trying to look up localhost. If you can ping it, then resolving localhost isn't your problem...

Comment: I believe that something is wrong there. /etc/hosts is okay. And pinging from localhost is ok. Only when typing localhost in any browser, the problem is appearing. I was suggested to try **nslookup localhost**, and indeed the output is: **Can't find localhost: No answer**.

Comment: Which, as I said before, you won't, because DNS servers are unlikely to resolve localhost. Do you have a system-wide proxy set?